# Is using flutter for both mobile and web for a social media platform feasible?

Tags: flutter, web, mobile, cross-platform, flutter-web

I'm new to flutter and I'm planning to create a social media platform something like Twitter, Instagram, or TikTok. I plan to use flutter for its web and mobile. But from what I can see since Flutter web is still in its early stages is it really achievable/feasible/practical(I don't what term to use) for the platform to only use flutter? Or is it much better to separate the web and mobile like using react/angular for the web and flutter for mobile? Also, Can you also provide what are the pros and cons for both scenarios?

Comment: In simple terms , if you want to build a webApp we can use Flutter, else there will be some struggle for building a complete website .

Answer (score 1):

Although flutter web is in its early stages, this platform has had an unstable version for a relatively long period and now, it has stable web release. Definitely, it has some challenges and specially lack of documentations for web version (due to its novelty), but it has power to provide reliable results. So, I think, yes you can use Flutter for your client-side. However, there are some difficulties in this platform that you can handle with native code as well.